# How to change to GridLayoutManager column dynamically

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I have a Recycler view with GridLayoutManager attached. By Default, it will display ONE COLUMN and if user will click on button, it will displays in TWO COLUMN.

```
adapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), productList);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
        setLayoutManager(true);
```

below is function where i am changing columns

```
  private void setLayoutManager(boolean isList) {
        if (isList) {
            adapter.VIEW_TYPE = 0 ;
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(1);
            //product_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            product_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        } else {
            adapter.VIEW_TYPE = 1 ;
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(2);
            product_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
        product_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       // product_recycler_view.notify();
       // product_recycler_view.notifyAll();

        System.out.println("clicked isList "+ isList);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  private void setLayoutManager(boolean isList) {
        if (isList) {
           product_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        } else {
           product_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
        product_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       // product_recycler_view.notify();
       // product_recycler_view.notifyAll();

        System.out.println("clicked isList "+ isList);
}
```